# How to run a python program using sourcelair?

Tags: python, ide

I'm trying to run a python program in the online IDE SourceLair. I've written a line of code that simply prints hello, but I am embarrassed to say I can't figure out how to RUN the program.

I have the console, web server, and terminal available on the IDE already pulled up. I just don't know how to start the program. I've tried it on Mac OSX and Chrome OS, and neither work.

I don't know if anyone has experience with this IDE, but I can hope. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Can I ask you why you are using SourceLair?

Well I just figured it out in about 2 mins....its the same as using any other editor for python.

All you have to do is to run it in the terminal. python (nameoffile).py

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using SourceLair because I am trying to run pygame on a chromebook on which I am not the administrator. Thus I do not have access to the terminal (crosh), and Python's IDLE is blocked. I had to resort to using an online IDE. I have already tried to do this, but just found out the only reason it was not working was because the file was not saved. Oy! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Antonis from SourceLair here.

In SourceLair, you get a fully featured terminal, plus a web server for running your Python applications.

For simple files, as you correctly found out, all you have to do is save the file and run it through your terminal, using `python <your-file.py>`.

If you want to run a complete web server, you can check out our server configuration guide here: https://help.sourcelair.com/webserver/configure-your-web-server/

Happy hacking!